# nosetest does not find tests in project

Tags: python-3.x, nose

I am having issues with nosetests.
I have used it a lot with python2 it is the first time with python3.

Apparently it does not find the tests in the project unless I do not specify the file.

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Connectors/trunk/modules/src/adam/src/adam/adam$ nosetests -v

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Connectors/trunk/modules/src/adam/src/adam/adam$ nosetests -v testing_tools/tests/test_testing_tools.py 
test_testing_tools.test_root_paths ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Connectors/trunk/modules/src/adam/src/adam/adam$
```

This is the project structure:

```
(adam_venv) lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Connectors/trunk/modules/src/adam/src/adam$ tree 
.
├── adam
│   ├── baseline
│   │   ├── action
│   │   │   ├── anomaly_score.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   ├── query_manager.py
│   │   │   ├── runner.py
│   │   │   └── tests
│   │   ├── database_manager.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── input_manager.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── query_manager.py
│   │   ├── runner.py
│   │   ├── status_file_manager.py
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── time_smoothed_baseliner.py
│   │   └── weighted_exp_baseline.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── utils
│   │       ├── cne_config.py
│   │       ├── cnx.py
│   │       ├── cnx_util.py
│   │       ├── config_executor.py
│   │       ├── console_spinner.py
│   │       ├── curl_utils.py
│   │       ├── file_lock.py
│   │       ├── files.py
│   │       ├── general_util.py
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── log_utils.py
│   │       ├── memory_utils.py
│   │       ├── popen_util.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       ├── remote_debugger.py
│   │       ├── rest_api.py
│   │       ├── shell_command.py
│   │       └── wait_utils.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config_manager.py
│   │   ├── config_validator.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── statistics_mapping.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module_setup
│   │   ├── alerts.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── daemon.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── logger.py
│   │   ├── messages.py
│   │   ├── paths_manager.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   │   └── paths_manager.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── setup.py
│   │   ├── sshcmd.py
│   │   ├── status_manager.py
│   │   ├── status.py
│   │   ├── status_util.py
│   │   └── tasks_manager.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── testing_tools
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│       │   └── testing_tools.cpython-38.pyc
│       ├── testing_tools.py
│       └── tests
│           ├── __pycache__
│           │   └── test_testing_tools.cpython-38.pyc
│           └── test_testing_tools.py
├── Distribution.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
└── setup.py

22 directories, 69 files
(adam_venv) lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/Connectors/trunk/modules/src/adam/src/adam$
```

I do not understand why it is not finding tests. 
Is there any difference in the usage between python2 and 3?

Comment: nosetests works as expected for me after replicating portions of your directory structure.  As a way of debugging, have you tried running with `--verbosity=4`?  Also as a way to debug, you may want to try running nose after descending to a subdir and see if that finds the test.

Comment: Thanks I have found the issue . Folders need to be executables while test files no

Comment: Looks like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781207/is-this-the-normal-behavior-of-nosetests-to-pick-only-none-executable-py.  If so, we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this the normal behavior of nosetests to pick only none executable .py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781207/is-this-the-normal-behavior-of-nosetests-to-pick-only-none-executable-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realised that nosetests was not finding the tests due to permission issues.

My conclusions are:

1. All folders should be marked as executable
2. All test files should not be executable.

I fixed with:

```
sudo chmod -r +X . && sudo chmod -r -x .
```